# Repeat jquery function

Tags: jquery, animation

I've got a jquery function that animates list items in sequence. It's working well, but I'd like it to repeat once all list items have been animated. I know this is probably simple but I can't figure it out :(

```
  $('ul').each(function() {
      $(this).children().each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).animate({opacity:0});
      });
      $(this).children().each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay((i++) * 0).animate({opacity:1});
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create one function `animate()` and call itself `recursively`. Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) of `$(ul).children().length * 1000` to set delay in calling function.

I guess you are having multiple such `ul`. So animation need to repeat based on number of `li` for respective `ul`.

```js
function animate(ul) {
  $(ul).children().each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).animate({opacity:0});
  });
  $(ul).children().each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(0).animate({opacity:1});
  });
  
  // Call for repeatedly animate once all animations are done.
  // Use timeout of $(this).children().length * 1000 to set delay in calling function.
  setTimeout(animate, $(ul).children().length * 1000, ul);
}

// Initiate animation.
$('ul').each(function() {
  animate(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will repeat animation for all `ul` lists only after every `li` item under it finishes its animation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul').each(function() {
        animateUl(this);
      });
    });

    function animateUl(elementUl) {

      $(elementUl).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).animate({
          opacity: 0
        });
        $(this).delay((i++) * 0).animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
      });


      setTimeout(animateUl, $(elementUl).children().length * 1000, elementUl);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's great, but is it possible to repeat the animation only after every li item has been animated? By repeating it every 3 seconds, it's repeating many times before it's finished, and the start of the animation is also delayed by 3 seconds

Comment: @jack_ edited answer. It will restart animation only after all `li` animations are done.